# I need to hide an open Access table from users

Tags: table, ms-access-2007

For application startup I had to open a table as part of some DAO.recordSet code.

```
 DoCmd.OpenTable "User", acNormal, acReadOnly
```

On running user tests, I want to distribute the desktop application as a run-time file (.accdr) but the access table is visible. All I can find is how to hide navigation area objects.

I, of course, do not want the table visible to users, so my question is how do I hide it?

Answer (score 1):

This article at [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/hide-access-tables-to-safeguard-them-from-users/) offers two approaches.

One is to set the table as hidden.

> Right-click the object in the Database window.
>
> Choose Properties.
>
> Click the Hidden option.

The other is to rename the table.

> Another way to hide a table is to add the prefix Usys to the table's name.

Both aren't really *secure,* as the object is still accessible, but it's not visible at least.